# Advantages to using URLField over TextField?

Tags: django, performance, postgresql, url, django-models

As I understand it you should always use a `TextField` for a variable length string when your using a PostgreSQL database because the speed difference between a `TextField` and a `CharField` is negligible with PostgreSQL.  I'm relativly new to Django, and was considering using a `TextField` for variable length urls in my database. I was wondering if there are any advantages to using the `URLField`?  Would it be considered bad form to use a `TextField` rather than a `URLField` for urls?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

URLField is actually CharField w/ supporting of Regexp-based URL pattern checking and a online validator(which was replaced by a RegEx based validator), you could use TextField if you don't care length-limitation of URL

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator

# in model
field = models.TextField(validators=[URLValidator()])
```

Furthermore, using of CharField or TextField depends on whether you want max-length constraint on the field, and which element type is more suitable for editing: textarea or input. On PostgreSQL side, there is no significant difference.

Comment: For the record, [IE can't load URLs longer than about 2,000 chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers), so you could just set `max_length` to 2000 on a `URLField` and call it a day.

Comment: Any reference to the deprecation of URLField ?

Comment: @pravin It is not the URLField but its previous validator been deprecated. The validator was accessing the URL online to verify, for now it is replaced by a regex validator to check the validation of URL format.

Comment: URLField default to max_length of 200, unless you specify some other value

Answer (score 5):

Try this class:

```python
class LongURLField(TextField):
    description = 'Long URL'

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, **kwargs):
        TextField.__init__(self, verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
        self.validators.append(validators.URLValidator())

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        # As with TextField, this will cause URL validation to be performed
        # twice.
        defaults = {
            'form_class': forms.URLField,
        }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(LongURLField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Comment: set max_length to 2000 and you have the perfect field :)

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#urlfield
Of course you can use CharField/TextField but handling user input and be sure whatever user enters is up-to you.

From the source code:

> # As with CharField, this will cause URL validation to be performed

If you see the [URLField source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/916e38802f151b34aaca487dc7e928946e81be73/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2288-L2289) you will find it's actually a CharField with URL validator.

Also there is other ready to use fields such as EmailField, ImageField, *Field!