# a Django URLField has fixed max_length as 200 characters

Tags: python, django

```
link = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True, default='')
```

I have already set the max_length as 500, but every time I tried to set this field with url larger than 200 characters, it still threw an error saying that `Ensure this value has at most 200 characters (it has 327).` Is this a Django restriction or something I forgot to set up?

Comment: One thing I'd check is the database table's column definition. 200 is the default length, so if you created your database before increasing the max_length it might still be set to 200.

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to actually update/migrate your database. This should happen upon initial `syncdb`, and ideally via a proper database migration using [django-south](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in Django version up to 1.6, or using the new Django migrations framework to be released in Django 1.7+.

For development purposes you can reset your DB (this will delete all data!) and recreate:

```
$ ./manage.py reset appname
$ ./manage.py syncdb
```

If you're using South migrations:

```
$ ./manage.py schemamigration --auto appname
$ ./manage.py syncdb --migrate
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is solved by now, but I ran into the same issue last week. While the answers regarding migrations are correct, it is worth noting that `URLField` is based on `CharField`. This means that the length limitations of `CharField` also apply to `URLField`, no matter what `max_length` you define (see also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#urlfield - this answer referred to Django 1.9 which was the latest release when I initially wrote it and this is still the same for [Django 3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#urlfield) in 2020).

Somewhat unrelated to the original question, but a possible problem even if you use the default `max_length=200` is how MySQL currently deals with UTF-8 text. You can find out more about this `VARCHAR()` indexing issue on https://serversforhackers.com/mysql-utf8-and-indexing or in the MySQL 5.7 manual on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-upgrading.html.

A possible solution for having a longer `URLField` has been posted in [Advantages to using URLField over TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052220/advantages-to-using-urlfield-over-textfield) - simply define a Textfield with the relevant validator.